# Google maps in china "Are they actually blocked"?

Tags: google-maps

Hi guys im working on a site which has a majority of chinese users. The problem is that it has been reported that google maps is not working for our users in china, because it is blocked.

I have trawled the net looking for a definitive answer but cant seem to find one, does any one know for sure whether it is blocked or not.

When I use a Chinese proxy I cannot reproduce the issue, and I am also not using https for my calls.

//**RESOLVED ISSUE**//
 is not blocked however if you are embedding a map the script makes a call to https://maps.google which is blocked hence why maps are not showing.

Thanks for all the help accepted

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The website **https://en.greatfire.org/** can be used to test URLs from behind the "Great Chinese Firewall".

Connections to maps are **patchy** at best, and is down most of the time. It is down at the moment too.

[image: Report-current]

There is also a list on the same website [here](https://en.greatfire.org/blocked-websites).

Clarification: `https://maps.google.com` is blocked, but `http://maps.google.com` isn't.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this url helps alot, I just need to find out why the maps are not working now :) Your post is also slightly incorrect try removing https and it will come through as unblocked, it is a known issue that https does not work.

Comment: Ok sorted the issue allthough I am calling out to a http://maps.google it makes a get request to https://maps.google which is blocked

Answer (score 1):

If its not blocked now, it maybe in the future . To be on the safe side you should avoid using google maps for now